# R Language - Waiting for user input with scan or readline

Tags: r, input, readline

I'm trying to get the user to input a few keywords for a query, and in my script I used either scan or readline. I tried it using the R-embeeded script editor (Windows) but when I execute the code, it uses my next lines of script as the standard input.
Here is my (part of) script

```
keywords <- scan(what=character(), nlines=1)
keywords <- paste(keywords, collapse=",")
keywords
```

And here is the output when executed from the editor

```
> keywords <- scan(what=character(), nlines=1)
1: keywords <- paste(keywords, collapse=",")
Read 4 items
> keywords
[1] "keywords"        "<-"              "paste(keywords," "collapse=\",\")"
```

Meanwhile when I use the source() command, I have my user input respected.

So is there any way to be able to input some things while executing the code right from the R software?

Comment: I just tried it in Rstudio, no problem. You should try Rstudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I use `readLInes`:

```
FUN <- function(x) {

    if (missing(x)) {
        message("Uhh you forgot to eneter x...\nPlease enter it now.")
        x <- readLines(n = 1)
    }
    x
}

FUN()
```

Or maybe something along these lines:

```
FUN2 <- function() {

    message("How many fruits will you buy")
    x <- readLines(n = 1)

    message("Good you want to buy %s fruits.\n Enter them now.")
    y <- readLines(n = x)
    paste(y, collapse = ", ")
}

FUN2()
```

**EDIT:** With your approach in Rgui...

```
FUN3 <- function(n=2) {
    keywords <- scan(what=character(), nlines=n)
    paste(keywords, collapse=",")
}

## > FUN3 <- function(n=2) {
## +     keywords <- scan(what=character(), nlines=n)
## +     paste(keywords, collapse=",")
## + }
## > FUN3()
## 1: apple
## 2: chicken
## Read 2 items
## [1] "apple,chicken"
```

Comment: I was trying to write something "smaller" (in one or two lines) but I will use your function as she' the one working. Thanks!
[EDIT] Actually I still have the problem, but I think it's only due to RGUI which use the script lines as stdin, so nothing else to do about it.

Comment: When I wrap yours up as a function and use on Rgui (Windows OS) this works.

Comment: Do you do it with running a whole script block? Your functions work fine when I use them in the console, but if I try to run something like 
`keywords <- FUN();keywords <- paste(blabla)`
it still uses the second line as the input

Comment: Ahh so you're sourcing this script (not interactive) and it won't ask for input.  Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not using the 'source()' function if that's what you mean, and I'm in interactive mode (already checked before). I'm just hitting a Ctrl-a / Ctrl-r to execute my whole code (or sometimes just blocks, but still directly from the editor)

Comment: Yeah that's interactive.  For me, in Rgui your approach (see my edit) works as does mine.