# Wait for user input from keyboard in R before next line of code - readline - Rstudio

Tags: r, input, wait, readline, pause

I want the user to choose data before analyzing the data but I can't get the code right to wait for user input…

```
check<-0
count<-0
data.choice<-function(){
while(check < 1 ){
  check <-as.numeric(readline('Choose 1 or 2 for analysing Data1 or Data2 respectively:  \n 1. "Data1" \n 2. "Data2" '));
  check <- ifelse(grepl("\\D",check),-1,as.integer(check))
  if(is.na(check)|check>2|count>3){
    count<-count+1
    print('Please type only 1 or 2...')
    break}  # breaks when hit enter
}
}
data.choice()
```

At this point it should display

> Choose 1 or 2 for analysing cells or exosomes respectively:
>   1. Data1
>
> 2. Data2

and WAIT FOR USER INPUT!!!

It works if i just run the piece of code above.
But if i run the whole thing it JUMPS TO THE NEXT LINE of code, for instance...:

```
if(check==1){   
print("Checking Data1")   
data1<-read.csv("file1.csv")
} 
else if(check==2){   
data1<-read.csv("file2.csv") 
}
```

I have read these other posts and it has helped me a little bit but I do not see how they can solve my problem.

[Running R script_Readline and Scan does not pause for user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084273/running-r-script-readline-and-scan-does-not-pause-for-user-input)

[stopping the script until a value is entred from keyboard in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507691/stopping-the-script-until-a-value-is-entred-from-keyboard-in-r/5522863#5522863)

[R Language - Waiting for user input with scan or readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253899/r-language-waiting-for-user-input-with-scan-or-readline)

Comment: When using interactive functions (readline or scan) you have to `source` your script and not run it as selection or the next line of code will be taken as input. R studio has an option for it on top right of the script.

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai
now it waits, but i got another problem…
If i just run 
while(check < 1 ){
  check <-as.numeric(readline('Choose 1 or 2 for analysing Data1 or Data2 respectively:  \n 1. "Data1" \n 2. "Data2" '));
  check <- ifelse(grepl("\\D",check),-1,as.integer(check))
  if(is.na(check)|check>2|count>3){
    count<-count+1
    print('Please type only 1 or 2...')
    break}  # breaks when hit enter
}
it works perfectly!
But it does not allocate the input value to the variable "check" when i define and run the function "data.choice" … 
Any clue?

Comment: Yes, the answer is because of scoping; your check variable into your function only exists inside the function (well at least when you assign to it with `<-`). Your function should return it (`return check` as last line) and in global script you should do `check <- data.choice()`

Comment: Thumb up! thanks again :-)