# readline does not prompt user input from Rprofile.site in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I have this little function in a file:

```
library(grDevices) # needed in Rprofile.site
readfun <- function()
  {
  message("interactive: ", interactive()) # tells TRUE
  rl <- readline("Write something: ")
  message("rl value is: ", rl)
  }
readfun()
```

I can `source` it in the R console witin Rstudio just fine.
I can write `source("thatfile.R")` in the Rrofile.site and calling Rterm via `R.exe` prompts input as expected. (I'm on Windows, btw).

But starting R with Rstudio, it will not prompt for user input.
Instead, the first typed command will not be executed but messaged back.

This could be related to [Wait for user input from keyboard in R before next line of code - readline - Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245442), but I can't find a way to get it to work...

Comment: I run the code in Rstudio and it... works? Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I think the problem is the code does not execute on Startup (or at least not all of it) when opening RStudio, but it does when starting R from the terminal. FWIW, I have been able to reproduce this issue (on Ubuntu 18.10 + R 3.5.3, whereas OP is on Windows + R ?.?.?)

Comment: I don't have it all sorted, but it could have something to do with this [quote from RStudio](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/04/19/r-for-enterprise-understanding-r-s-startup/): "RStudio starts R a bit differently than running R from the terminal. Technically, RStudio doesn’t “start” R, it uses R as a library, either as a DLL on Windows or as a shared object on Mac and Linux. The main difference is that the script wrapped around R’s binary is not run, and any customization to the script will not take affect. To see the script try: `cat $(which R)`", though I don't see how that would cause this

Comment: To be clear, the behavior I see when starting RStudio after adding this to `Rprofile.site` is `interactive: TRUE` is printed, but then the `> ` prompt is shown rather than `Write something: `. Whatever I type is then echoed; for example if I type a, then Enter, I see `rl value is: a`. When running R from the terminal it works completely as expected. The only difference I see is whether the prompt is printed. This is a very strange issue

Comment: I (OP) have R 3.5.2 and @duckmayr: yes, that's it. Prompt ist not printed and the rest of the function is not executed until something is typed in the console.

Comment: Might be related to the fact the readline is supposed to be used in interactive mode only. From the documentation: 'Return character vector of length one. Both leading and trailing spaces and tabs are stripped from the result.

In non-interactive use the result is as if the response was RETURN and the value is "". '